# Copying from outside and pasting in vim

Tags: macos, vim, clipboard

I can use 'yy' and 'p' to copy and paste in my Vim file, but when i copy some Python code from outside and try to do a 'p' in my Vim file it just pastes the last copied thing inside my Vim.

Is there anyway i can sync my vim and system clipboards ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to `~/.vimrc` (create it if it doesn't exist):

`set clipboard=unnamed`

Comment: doesnt seem to work either, will i have to restart the system for it to come ion effect ??

Comment: No, restarting Vim should be enough. You should take romainl's advice and check if your Vim has been compiled with clipboard support to achieve the desired behaviour.

Comment: yeah it did the trick. Restarted Vim and it now just works with the 'p' shortcut. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the command below:

```
"+gP
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when i do this in the esc mode it says  
Nothing in register g.

Comment: That's `"` followed by `+` followed by `g` followed by `p`.

Comment: @yappa the command is the quotation mark followed by the plus sign followed by the g letter followed by the capital P letter. Did you try this exactly?

Answer (score 3):

1. See if your Vim is built with clipboard support with this command, it should echo `1`:

   ```
   :echo has("clipboard")
   ```
2. If you get a `1`, use `"+p`.
3. If you get a `0`, install a Vim built with clipboard support. MacVim is the most obvious choice.

Comment: it did give me a 1 and "+p worked as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From change.txt:

> **Selection and drop registers "*, "+ and "~**
>                                      Use these registers for storing and retrieving the selected text for
>   the GUI.
>   When the clipboard is not
>   available or not         working, the unnamed register ("") is used
>   instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
   " map to paste from clipboard with Ctrl-Alt-p
   " put this mapping in your ~/.vimrc file
   nmap <C-M-P> "+p
   imap <C-M-P> <esc>"+pA
```

With this maps I have an easy way to past from outside.